# uncaught exception relaunching the calling activity?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a large android app and recently I am seeing that on any uncaught exception, the exception is shown in the DDMS Logcat and following that the calling parent activity gets relaunched (onCreate get's called). Ideally the application should just exit.

We are using ARCA crash application reporting, but commented out that and still see the same activity getting relaunched. I am calling the startActivityForResults and the android manifest has android:finishOnTaskLaunch true for the activity as well as the subactivity.

Any pointers on what could be causing the activity relaunch on the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the expected behavior of force closes.  The user gets informed of the exception, when they acknowledge it the system tries to get them back as close as possible to their current state, i.e., the last activity that worked.

I'm not sure why this behavior wouldn't be desired, but you probably need to come up with your own method of recognizing that the activity was restarted because of a crash and immediately exit in onCreate.

Edit:
I just put together a test app:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText("test");
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setText("test2");
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When you push the button in Test2, the exception is thrown.  Android shows a force close dialog, and when you click OK in the dialog, it takes you back to Test.  That is what I meant by the default behavior.

The best way to deal with this is to fix your app so that it never throws an exception.

As a last resort, you could add a handler for dealing with uncaught exceptions: [uncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).  This prevents the force close dialog from being shown in the first place, so you can do as you like.

Comment: Thanks Marya... This is not the default behavior for Android applications. If you try any sample apps and a crash happens, the application exits. I tried simulating the case in another simple app and it crashes "fully". I was looking for pointers on what could be causing the relaunch of the app.

Comment: And regarding "why", the application is in a bad state when the activity is relaunched and I do not want to handle the invalid states in the code for all my activities at this point of time. Closing the app and allowing acra/marketplace to report the exception for me seems to be  better.

Comment: Mayra... thanks.. Instead of using StartActivityForResult, if you use StartActivity, the behavior is little different. Anyway, will go ahead with clearing other exceptions. Thanks for your insights.